# Equivalent command for itemize lists to \insertenumlabel

Tags: beamer, lists

What is the command for inserting the current itemize lists **shape** in Beamer ?

Or is there another way to get this label ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the correct symbol for the current level of the `itemize` use

```
\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[circle]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

  \begin{itemize}
  \item xxx
    \begin{itemize}
    \item yyy \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}{}
    \item xx \usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. And you could give the answer to my other question : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254472/beamer-hyperlink-make-itemize-symbols-jumpable.